# ARKit detect house exterior planes

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit

I know that ARKit is able to detect and classify planes on A12+ processors. It does the job reasonably well inside the house, but what about the outside? Is it able to detect windows and doors if I move around a house a little? I tried it myself and the result did not satisfy me: i moved around the building too much and still ARKit did not distinguish wall from the window.

I used app from here for tests: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_visualizing_planes
I’m I doing everything correct? Maybe there is some third party library to detect house parts better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you test the sample app outside and try to use ARKit to detect the surfaces on the exterior of a house it will not work. ARKit is built to map flat surfaces and their orientations (horizontal/vertical). This means ARKit can understand that a surface is flat, is either a wall or a floor. When you attempt to "map" the exterior of a house, ARKit will only detect the horizontal surfaces as walls, it cannot distinguish between walls and windows.

You will need to develop/source an AI model and run it against the camera data using CoreML to enable your app to distinguish between windows and walls on the exterior of a house.

ARKit Plane tracking documentation for reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_visualizing_planes

a couple articles about ARKit with CoreML
https://www.rightpoint.com/rplabs/dev/arkit-and-coreml 
https://medium.com/s23nyc-tech/using-machine-learning-and-coreml-to-control-arkit-24241c894e3b

**[Update]**
Yes you are correct, for A12+ devices Apple does allow for plane classification. I would assume the issue with exterior windows vs interior is either distance to the window (too far for the CV to properly classify) or Apple has tuned it more for interior windows vs exterior. The difference may seem trivial but to a CV algorithm it's quite different.

Comment: ARKit can classify planes when running on a device with A12 or higher.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arplaneanchor/classification